# find all paterns of a regex in a string

Tags: python-3.x, regex

I have an overly complicated regex that as far as I know is correct

```
route = r"""[\s+|\(][iI](\.)?[vV](\.)?(\W|\s|$)?
               |\s intravenously|\s intravenous
               |[\s|\(][pP](\.)?[oO](\.)?(\W|\s|$)
               |\s perorally|\s?(per)?oral(ly)?|\s intraduodenally
               |[\s|\(]i(\.)?p(\.)?(\W|\s|$)?  
               |\s intraperitoneal(ly)?
               |[\s|\(]i(\.)?c(\.)?v(\.)?(\W|\s|$)? 
               |\s intracerebroventricular(ly)?
               |[\s|\(][iI](\.)?[gG](\.)?(\W|\s|$)?
               |\s intragastric(ly)?
               |[\s|\(]s(\.)?c(\.)?(\W|\s|$)?
               |subcutaneous(ly)?(\s+injection)?
               |[\s|\(][iI](\.)?[mM](\.)?(\W|\s|$)? 
               |\sintramuscular
          """
```

With `re.search` I manage to get one of the numerous patterns if it is a string

```
s = 'Pharmacokinetics parameters evaluated after single IV or IM'

m = re.search(re.compile(route, re.X), s)
m.group(0)
' IV '
```

I read somewhere else to use `re.findall`  to find all the occurrences.
In my dreams, this would return:

```
['IV', 'IM']
```

Unfortunately instead the result is:

```
[('',
  '',
  ' ',
  '',
  '',
  '',
  '',
  '',
  '',
  '',
  '',
  '',
  '',
  '',
  '',
  '',
  '',
  '',
  '',
  '',
  '',
  '',
  '',
  '',
  '',
  '',
  '',
  '',
  ''),
 ('',
  '',
  '',
  '',
  '',
  '',
  '',
  '',
  '',
  '',
  '',
  '',
  '',
  '',
  '',
  '',
  '',
  '',
  '',
  '',
  '',
  '',
  '',
  '',
  '',
  '',
  '',
  '',
  '')]
```

Comment: what patterns does the re have to recognize?

Comment: Not that your pattern starts with a mere `|` I think you meant to put all the alternatives in a grouping like `(?:....|...|....)` Then other thing to know is that re.findall returns the values of the capture groups.

Comment: @GoldenLion: this was indicated at the very bottom of my post but no easy to see I believe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the excerpt you show:

```
\b
(?: i 
    (?: ntra
        (?: cerebroventricular (?:ly)?
          | duodenally
          | gastric (?:ly)?
          | muscular
          | peritoneal (?:ly)?
          | venous (?:ly)?
        ) \b
      | \.? (?: [gmpv] | c \.? v ) \b \.?
    )
  |
    (?:per)? oral (?:ly)? \b
  |
    p \.? o \b \.?
  |
    subcutaneous (?:ly)? (?: \s+ injection )? \b
)
```

[demo](https://onlinegdb.com/m6OAhz5W5)

Advices:

- You have a very long pattern, you already use the re.X option that is a good thing, exploit it to the maximum by formatting the pattern in a rigorous and readable way. Eventually, use the alphabetic order. It may sound silly, but what a time saver! It's also possible to add inline comments starting with `#`.
- you have many character classes with the same character in two different cases => use the global re.I flag too and write your pattern in lower case.
- I see you try to delimit substrings with things like `\s` or the ugly `[\s|\(]` (you don't need to escape a parenthesis in a character class and `|` doesn't mean OR inside it) and `(\W|\s|$)?` (that is totally useless since you make it optional). Forget that and use word boundaries `\b` (read about it to well understand in which cases it matches).
- Use `re.findall` instead or re.search since you expect several matches in a single string.
- Use non-capturing groups `(?: ... )` instead of capturing groups `( ... )`.  (when a pattern contains capture groups, `re.findall` returns only the capture groups content and not the whole match).
- factorize your pattern from the left (the pattern is tested from left to right, a factorization from the left reduces the number of branches to test). With this in mind, this subpattern `(?:per)? oral (?:ly)? \b  |  p \.? o \b \.?` could be rewritten in this way: `oral (?:ly)? \b | p (?: eroral (?:ly)? \b | \.? o \.?)`
- you can also factorize from the right when possible. It's not a great improvement but it reduces the pattern size.

Comment: Thanks for refactoring my horrible regex. As you noticed I am not an expert and this is a regex I have been editing for years without really taking the time to clean it.

Comment: What does (?: mean

Answer (score 0):

use (?:.)? tp find none or one period in the word pattern.  Notice I found ip or i.p.  The pattern matching does not exclude patterns within patterns, for example ip next to POip.

print ("find combinations of words with or without periods")

```
  data="single intravenously intravenous IV oral PO intraperitoneal intraperitoneally i.p. ip"

matches=re.findall(r'[iI](?:\.)?[vV](?:\.)?|intravenous(?:ly)?|[pP](?:\.)?[oO](?:\.)?|peroral(?:ly)?|oral(?:ly)?|[iI](?:\.)?[pP](?:\.)?|intraperitoneal(?:ly)?',data)
print(matches)
```

output:

```
['intravenously', 'intravenous', 'IV', 'oral', 'PO', 'intraperitoneal', 'intraperitoneally', 'i.p.', 'ip']
```